# Total of a particular column from html table having multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, html

My Java Script Code

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#addRow').click(function(){
            var html = $('#row_template').html();
            $('#dataTable').append(html);
            $(".tablerow").each(function(index) {
                $(this).html(index + 1);
            });
        });
        $('#deleteRow').click(function(){
            $('#dataTable .mychkbox:checked').parents('tr').remove();
        });
        $('#dataTable').on('change','.select-desc',function(){
            var cur_val = $(this).val();
            $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="rate[]"]').val(cur_val);
        });
        $('#dataTable').on('keyup','input[name="qty[]"]', function(){
            var qty = +$(this).val();
            var unit = +$(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="rate[]"]').val();
            $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="amt[]"]').val(qty*unit);
            var totamt = 0 ;
            var theTbl = document.getElementById('dataTable');

            for(var i=0;i<theTbl.length;i++)
            {
                for(var j=0;j<theTbl.rows[i].cells.length;j++)
                {
                    totamt = totamt + theTbl.rows[i].cells[4].InnerHTML;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <div class="left">
        <h2><span class="orange">Work Order Items</span></h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" id="addRow" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Remove Row" id="deleteRow" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="0" width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Item Description</label></td>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Rate</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>Cert No</td>
            <td>C Date</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="row_template" style="display:none">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="mychkbox" /></td>
            <td class="tablerow"></td>
            <td>
               <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT itrate,CONCAT(itname,'|',itcode) as mname FROM ITMAST ";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                    echo "<select name='itname[]' id='itname' class='select-desc' >";
                    echo "<option value=''>-- Select Item --</option>";
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        {
                            echo "<option value = '{$row['itrate']}'";
                                if ($pitcode == $row['itrate'])
                                    echo "selected = 'selected'";
                            echo ">{$row['mname']}</option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty" size="6" class='rightJustified'></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate" size="8" class='rightJustified' readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amt[]" id="amt" size="9" class='rightJustified' readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" size="8" name="txtcertno[]"></td>
            <td><input type="date" maxlength="10" size="10" name="txtcdate[]"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

I am trying to take total of amount column i.e. amt[] after each entry of a row, but I am not getting it properly, I have written Javascript function for the same but some thing may be wrong in it

Comment: and what do you get then? any error? log? what value is returned?

Comment: I am getting value as zero when I added alert statement to display value of totamt in javascript

Comment: you get the html content of your cell, not the value... innerHTML returns the innerHTML code from your TD, so it returns "<input ...."

Comment: btw, why do you have 2 loops? you only need 1 loop to loop through the rows as you just need one of the rows'cell value...

Comment: How I can get value which can be added

Comment: Yes Understood, column loop is not required which I removed in my code but still I am getting 0 as totamt

Comment: Please start here : http://jsfiddle.net/nxm0ye54/3/ and edit this so you can show me what's wrong.

Comment: Sir I worked in above link and made some changes in code, I did get value of amount = qty * rate correctly, but totamt is zero which I am taking total of all amount from table column 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not correct all of your mistakes,
You should check @Samurai answer for more details (such as use of the 'id' and other things)

Main problem was, as I said in comment, use of innerHTML which returned "

another thing, your theTbl var was not good, you could never call .length on it. To solve that, you had to handle it this way :

```
var totamt = 0 ;
var theTbl = $('#dataTable');
//You are using jquery, so use jquery selectors...
var trs = theTbl.find("input[name='amt[]']");
//find there the AMT[] INPUTS, not the rows...
console.log("how many amt inputs? : "+trs.length);
for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++)
{
    //fetch the inputs, and make your calculations here
    console.log("amount from row "+i+" = "+trs[i].value);
    //do not forget, as Samurai said, to convert html to numeric...
    $("#total").html(totamt+=parseFloat(trs[i].value));         
}
```

Here is a working solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/nxm0ye54/20/

Comment: Sir I added alert statement in jsfiddle but it shows Nan

Comment: why do you add Alert? Just add 1 row, set rate, THEN set quantity, and you will see the $("total") label that will change. Add other rows, and that'll do the same. Isn't it what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

First to point out a few mistakes:

- `$('#row_template').html()`: browsers automatically add `tbody` to the table, so you end up having multiple `tbody` in your main table which of course won't cause any problem on its own, if that's the desired output.
- You're misusing `ID`. Each `tr` has multiple `td` with `input`s that share the same `ID`. Instead you should use `class`.
- To calculate the total amount you're getting the `innerHTML` of the cells which don't hold a number, but an `input` element. Instead you want the value these `input` elements are holding.
- You need to convert the values to numbers before doing math on them, otherwise it will assume they're string and just put them beside each other. (e.g. 0+1+2 = 012 and not 3). You should use `parseInt` or `parseFlout` which the latter suits this case better.

A few modifications to your code:

```
 $('#addRow').click(function () {
     var html = $('#row_template tbody').html();
     $('#dataTable tbody').append(html);
```

And - since you're using jQuery - I completely changed the calculation to a jQuery version:

```
//gt(0) cause the first row contains headers
//eq(5) cause we want the 6th cell (Amount)
var totamt = 0;
$('#dataTable tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
    var newAmt = $(this).find('td:eq(5) input[type=text]').val();
    totamt += parseFloat(newAmt);
});
```